# How to query nested indexes using Retire

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

I've got an `Article` model:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  settings default_options do
    mapping do
      indexes :id, index: :not_analyzed
      indexes :roles do
        indexes :machine_name, analyzer: 'keyword'
      end
      indexes :published_at, type: 'date', include_in_all: false
    end
  end
end
```

where the default_options is:

```
index: { store: { type: Rails.env.test? ? :memory : :niofs },
         analysis: {
           analyzer: {
             default: {
               tokenizer: "standard",
               filter: ["asciifolding", "lowercase", "snowball"],
               char_filter: ["html_strip"]
             }
           }
        }
```

I'm simply trying to search articles while filtering roles, but I don't have any idea how to do so. I've been trying something like that without success:

```
Tire.search("article") do
  query { string 'foo bar baz' }
  filter :nested, { path:'roles',
                    query: {
                      filtered: {
                        query: {
                          match_all: {}
                        },
                        filter: {
                          term:{'roles.machine_name' => ['da']}
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
end
```

This give me that error:

```
QueryParsingException[[development-oaciq::application-article] [nested] nested object under path [roles] is not of nested type];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508389/elastic-search-nested), it seems the `nested` filter wasn't required, it could be done like this:

```
Tire.search("article") do
  query do
    string 'foo bar baz'
    term 'roles.machine_name', 'test'
  end
end
```